# Switching page's doesnt work

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, gsap

I have a problem I can't figure out I'm looking trough the code for hours 
I've made a website in flash but it won't go to page 4 de page is filled just like the others the code is exactly the same I've added the greenshock lite tween. but the 4th page just doesn't open when I play the movie.

The only thing that I get is

TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at Tommorowland_Scene1_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()[Tommorowland_Scene1_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:25]

```
next_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, nextImage);
```

that is the other thing my slider doesn't work anymore haven't changed a thing so I don't know if greenshock litetween is messing something up but its annoying as #!$@

```
        import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import com.greensock.*;
    stop();


    button1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, button1_clicked);
    function button1_clicked(e:MouseEvent):void{
            TweenLite.to(balk_mc, 1, {x:141, y:balk_mc.y});
            gotoAndStop("page1");
    }

    button2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, button2_clicked);
    function button2_clicked(e:MouseEvent):void{
            TweenLite.to(balk_mc, 1, {x:330, y:balk_mc.y});
            gotoAndStop("page2");
    }

    button3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, button3_clicked);
    function button3_clicked(e:MouseEvent):void{
            TweenLite.to(balk_mc, 1, {x:551, y:balk_mc.y});
            gotoAndStop("page3");
    }
            var number:Number = 1;

    next_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, nextImage);

    checkNumber();
    function nextImage(event:MouseEvent):void {
        //trace("next button geklikt!");
        number++;
        loader.source = "images/tommorrowland"+number+".png";
        checkNumber();
    }

    previous_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, previousImage);

    function previousImage(event:MouseEvent):void {
        //trace("previous button geklikt!");
        number--;
        loader.source = "images/tommorrowland"+number+".png";
        checkNumber();
    }

    function checkNumber():void {
        next_btn.visible = true;
        previous_btn.visible = true;
        if(number == 4){
            next_btn.visible = false;
        }
        if(number == 1){
            previous_btn.visible = false;
        }
    }

    button4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, button4_clicked);
    function button4_clicked(e:MouseEvent):void{
            TweenLite.to(balk_mc, 1, {x:735, y:balk_mc.y});
            gotoAndStop("page4");
    }
```

I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

if this is the line generating the error:

```
next_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, nextImage);
```

Then **next_btn** does not exist on the timeline where you are trying to set the mouse event on it.  Make sure **next_btn** is created and or is present before the mouseEvent listener is added.